# Parsing XML using JSON PHP and outputting data

Tags: php, xml, json

I am trying to parse some xml in PHP and can build the correct url to fetch the data, but I am stuck on the process of determining how to look at the structure so I can avoid errors like this

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\sportchecker\soccer.php on line 39
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  252360  {main}( )   ..\sports.php:0
```

Here is an example URL http://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/leagues?sportid=29, are their any tools that can tell me how to navigate through the tree in php code?  The call I make with the API key has lots of data returned.  Here is my code below

```
$url = "http://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/feed?sportid=$sport_id&leagueid=$league_id&clientid=$client_id&apikey=$api_key&oddsformat=$oddsformat";
    $json_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

    // output the xml data
    $wSports = $parsed_json->sports->sport->id;
     echo "Status :  ${wSports} ";

     // test if url is correct
     echo $url;
```

Edit: here is a sample of the data, I am trying to get the teams and time back.

```
<rsp status="ok">
<fd>
<fdTime>1385326075704</fdTime>
<sports>
<sport>
<id>29</id>
<leagues>
<league>
<id>1739</id>
<events>
<event>
<startDateTime>2013-11-25T22:59:00Z</startDateTime>
<id>334321824</id>
<IsLive>No</IsLive>
<status>I</status>
<drawRotNum>2056</drawRotNum>
<homeTeam type="Team1">
<name>Atletico Huracan</name>
<rotNum>2054</rotNum>
</homeTeam>
<awayTeam type="Team2">
<name>Talleres Cordoba</name>
<rotNum>2055</rotNum>
</awayTeam>
<periods>
<period lineId="117000156">
<number>0</number>
<description>Game</description>
<cutoffDateTime>2013-11-25T22:59:00Z</cutoffDateTime>
<spreads>
<spread>
<awaySpread>0.25</awaySpread>
<awayPrice>1.869</awayPrice>
<homeSpread>-0.25</homeSpread>
<homePrice>1.97</homePrice>
</spread>
</spreads>
```

Comment: you cant parse xml file to json structure. use simplexml_load_file instead. [go to php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use simplexml.

```
$sports = new SimpleXMLElement($parsedJson);
$sports->sport[0]->id
```

Comment: Added this to my code and I get 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Comment: Maybe it's not valid XML. Hard to tell by the sample give. Anyway, it's not json.